# error while using npm install express mongoose multer dotenv

Tags: npm, hadoop-yarn

i am trying to build backend of an application , to start with i ran the command  "npm install express multer dotenv mongoose" and this throws me the following error " npm ERR! Cannot read properties of null (reading 'resolve') " please help , also i have tried to uninstall node, npm and re install again but didnt work
if i use yarn add command , it shows dependencies are added but i dont see any files the directory like node_modules , package,json etc

tried uninstalling and reinstalling node and npm